# Ntpd drifting, very fast

Tags: 20.04, ntp, amd-ryzen

I have to run stop ntp/ntpdate/start ntp every day, since my Laptop (ThinkPas AMD64 Rhyzen, Ubuntu 20.04) looses half an hour a day

Here is my ntp.conf (almost the default):

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
leapfile /usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

server aragorn.groumpf.org iburst
server numenor.groumpf.org iburst

restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

restrict source notrap nomodify noquery
```

I'm not a Linux newbie, but simply cannot see what's happening

Thanks for help

Xavier

EDIT : the requested additional info, clock has been ntpdate'd just now:

```
[xavier@imladris ~]$ cat /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
-0.189
[xavier@imladris ~]$ timedatectl status
               Local time: Wed 2021-11-03 08:58:59 CET
           Universal time: Wed 2021-11-03 07:58:59 UTC
                 RTC time: Wed 2021-11-03 08:16:53
                Time zone: Europe/Paris (CET, +0100)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: n/a
[xavier@imladris ~]$ ntpq -pn
remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
+176.31.180.205  193.52.184.106   2 u   35   64    1   15.545  309.431 255.807
*192.168.100.144 193.52.184.106   2 u   10   64    3    0.166  490.224 445.668
```

Comment: I assume you do not modify the clock manually and your timezone is correct. Also, do you see anything strange in file `/var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift`?

Comment: Also NTPd isn't fully supported anymore in 20.04; I'd recommend giving systemd-timesyncd a chance (the default) or if you want/need an explicit tools/server then 'chrony' - is it any different with those?

Comment: What are the contents of your laptop's `/var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift` file? What is the output of the command `timedatectl status`? Please, [edit] your Question to add this information. Also, from time to time, check the output of the command `ntpq -pn`; one of your ntp server's IP address should have a `*` in front of it, the other a `+` character.

Comment: Are you using `systemd-timesyncd` or `ntpd` as your intended NTP service? This is very unclear. If you use `ntpd`, this means you've changed from the default. It seems whatever NTP service you intend to use is not working. Reverting to the default `systemd-timesyncd` would make it easier for you to get help.

Comment: I suggest you remove `ntp` and install `systemd-timesyncd`. After that, check with `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd` that is "active (running)" and with `timedatectl status` you should see `System clock synchronized: yes` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remove `ntp`:

```
sudo apt remove ntp
```

and install `systemd-timesyncd` (which should be installed by default on all new installations):

```
sudo apt install systemd-timesyncd
```

After that, check with

```
systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
```

that "systemd-timesyncd.service" is "active (running)" and with

```
timedatectl status
```

you should see something like:

```
...
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
...
```

---

<sup>*See also [this](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-ntp).*</sup>

Answer (score -1):

I finally gave up with ntpd, installed chrony successful

Thanks to all who helped

Cheers

Xavier